# C++ understanding pointers

Tags: c++

I have a bit of code that I'm trying to analyze to study up on pointers and I'd like to ask for some help on whether I'm interpreting it correctly and if I'm not can someone help interpret it for me because I still find pointers to be confusing. You will be able to see my interpretations right after the //.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
    int a[] = {5, 10, 15};

    PointerMystery(&x, y, a);
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void PointerMystery(int *pa, int b, int c[]) {
// *pc will return array c
    int *pc = c;

// *pa which returns the address of x will now make x = 20.     
    *pa = 20;
// b which was 3 is now equal to 15, therefore y = 15
    b = 15;
// *pc which returned a array is now 15(im not so sure about this?)
    *pc = b;
// im not sure what is happening here either?
    pc += 2;
// *pc will return the value (20) - 10?
    *pc = *pa - 10;

    cout << *pa << " " << b << " " << *pc << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can easily test your thoughts.

Comment: `pc += 2;` moves you along two places in the array `c[]`. Be careful not to run past the end of the array. Google "Pointer Arithmetic" for more details.

Comment: Arrays decays to pointers when passed as arguments to functions, so in the function the variable `c` is already a pointer. And when using the dereferencing operator you don't get the address of the pointer, you get the value of what it points to. To get the address stored in a pointer, just use the pointer itself (pointers are, essentially, integer variables whose value is an address).

Comment: Just debug the code! Why do you think this is worth a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer variables are just what their names implies, variables that point to something.

It might be easier to understand if you think about it graphically, and step by step. So...

---

When the `PointerMystery` function is called you have the variables `pa`, `b` and `c`:

```
+----+     +---+
| pa | --> | 5 |
+----+     +---+

+---+
| 3 |
+---+

+---+     +----+----+----+
| c | --> |  5 | 10 | 15 |
+---+     +----+----+----+
```

---

After you assign `pc` you have

```
+---+   
| c | --\
+---+    \    +----+----+----+
          >-> |  5 | 10 | 15 |
+----+   /    +----+----+----+
| pc | -/
+----+
```

---

You then do `*pa = 20;` so you have

```
+----+     +----+
| pa | --> | 20 |
+----+     +----+
```

---

Then you do `*pc = b;`, where `b` is `15`, and since `pc` really just points to the *first* element of the passed array that mean you change the first element:

```
+---+   
| c | --\
+---+    \    +----+----+----+
          >-> | 15 | 10 | 15 |
+----+   /    +----+----+----+
| pc | -/
+----+
```

---

You then increase the pointer `pc` to point to the *third* element of the passed array:

```
+---+     +----+----+----+
| c | --> | 15 | 10 | 15 |
+---+     +----+----+----+
                    ^
+----+              |
| pc | -------------/
+----+
```

---

You then change the value where `pc` is pointing to the value of where `pa` is pointing minus `10`, and the value of where `pa` is pointing is `20` which gives `10` after the subtraction:

```
+---+     +----+----+----+
| c | --> | 15 | 10 | 10 |
+---+     +----+----+----+
                    ^
+----+              |
| pc | -------------/
+----+
```

---

Other things that might be good to know about pointers, is that arrays decays to pointers to their first element when you pass them to a function. That's the reason that `c` is a pointer and where it points.

Also, you can use both array indexing syntax and pointer syntax for both arrays and pointer. You can do this for arrays since they decays to pointers to their first element, and for pointers as a short-hand for `*(ptr + x)`. In fact, for both pointers and arrays, `*(ptr_or_array + x)` is equivalent to `ptr_or_array[x]`.

The last bit also explains why adding two to the `pc` pointer makes it points to the *third* element, `*(pc + 0)` is equivalent to `pc[0]` and `*(pc + 2)` is equivalent to `pc[2]`, which since array indexes are zero based is the third element.